# ffmpeg Color Correction: Gamma, Brightness and Saturation

Tags: ffmpeg, color-correction

How is ffmpeg used with a video filter circa 2017 to adjust gamma/contrast, brightness and saturation?

Stack Exchange resources that are a few years old point to the filter `mp=eq2=`, but it seems to be [deprecated<sup>1</sup> and replaced](https://wjwoodrow.wordpress.com/2015/07/12/more-ffmpeg-hell/) with just `eq=`. The link does not reveal a good understanding of the setting ranges, however.

How is `eq=` (or equivalent filters) used? E.g., what is the format and appropriate settings/ranges?

For my personal usage, I'd like to keep gamma where it is, while increasing brightness and saturation a fair bit, for a dark video.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>Throws error message: `No such filter: 'mp'`</sub>

Comment: Checks the [docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#eq), and look into the [curves or pp filter](http://video.stackexchange.com/q/14603/1871) as well.

Comment: The syntax is the same as for all filters. i.e. `filtername=option1=value1:option2=value2:option3=value3...` These can be in any order.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

These settings helped me to lighten up a dark video using the filter `eq`, with some added saturation.

#### Syntax:

> `filtername=option1=value1:option2=value2:option3=value3...` These can be in any order.

#### Filter ranges and all options:

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#eq

#### Preview:

`ffplay -vf eq=brightness=0.06:saturation=2 INPUT.MOV`

#### Render:

`ffmpeg -i INPUT.MOV -vf eq=brightness=0.06:saturation=2 -c:a copy OUTPUT.MOV`

---

**Alternative filters**: [`curves` and `pp`](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/14603/1871).

Comment: the preview ffplay is an awesome added value

Comment: works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

Gamma correction is likely to be a better choice than brightness, to stretch the histogram to the right rather than push it over:

```
# tinker with numbers
ffplay -vf eq=gamma=1.5:saturation=1.3 original.vid 

# render
ffmpeg -i original.vid -vf eq=gamma=1.5:saturation=1.3 \
    -c:a copy  outfile.vid
```

Comment: Is there a reason the saturation needs to be changed with the gamma?

Comment: Been a few years but my recollection is that when you brighten a dark video it looks a bit muted color-wise.

Answer (score 14):

I'd also try [curves](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#curves-1):

```
ffmpeg -i input.vid -vf "curves=all='0/0 0.5/1 1/1'" -codec:a copy -codec:v libx264 -y output.vid
```

The `0.5/1` maps mid-range brightness (0.5) to full bright (1)

Comment: One reason to use curves instead of eq: the latter seems to affect pixel format. If you convert from YUV to BGRP for conventional blending purposes, but blending for some unexplainable reason happens in YUV anyway, replacing eq with curves may help. Another filter that seems to mess up blending is normalize.